# JFrame - how no to change the size?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, alerts

I'm working on my first Swing project and I need to know how to do it so that the user can not change the size, size or size, and when he tries the program he sends an alert that does not leave him continue until you press accept.

```
setResizable(false); // To not change the Frame size
setSize(400, 440); // Frame size
```

Comment: `setResizable` should prevent user from changing the size.  Is your "size,size or size" is just a pun or do you mean something else?

Comment: *"and when he tries the program he sends an alert that does not leave him continue until you press accept"* - set `setResizable` will prevent the user from resizing the app, I'm not sure what the point of the popup would be - apart from to aggravate them further

Comment: *"..what I was asked for the project"* Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: BTW - comments in languages other than English are useless to most people who visit the site. Please remove them or translate them into English.

Answer (score 0):

Use ComponentAdapter with componentResized.

```
frame.addComponentListener( new ComponentAdapter() {
    public void componentResized( ComponentEvent componentEvent ) {
        // your code goes here, an error message, etc...
    }
} ) ;
```